# Reschedule US Visa consular interview appointment after OFC appointment already completed

Tags: visas, usa, b1-b2-visas

I have a consular US Visa interview on 7th December. I already had
my OFC appointment for biometrics in late November which I
attended. Now when I login to ustraveldocs.com and wish to reschedule my consular appointment, it takes me to rescheduling the OFC appointment screen. Will I have to attend the OFC appointment again if I want to reschedule just my consular interview?

Also, I had one consular Visa interview already rejected. This is my 2nd application. So do I need to have an OFC appointment every time I apply for Visa?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Short answer:**

Depending on your country, the answer will vary. In certain countries, you don't need to have an OFC every time you apply for a visa. The website should automatically skip the OFC page, but if it doesn't do that I'd recommend reaching out to someone at the embassy either in-person on via the phone.

In other countries, the US embassy supports walk-in appointments if your situation is suitably dire and thus you also don't need to reschedule an OFC.

However, in many countries, the deadline for re-scheduling the visa appointment is 24 hours before the OFC appointment. This means that after your OFC, you cannot reschedule the visa interview. Many people, as a result of this, schedule their OFC as close as possible to the visa so that they have as much leeway as they can. If you end up missing your visa, you can reschedule both at a fee and that is your only remaining option, sadly.

**Here is a sampling of the raw information I've collected**. It's extremely contradictory and seemingly senseless because it is from multiple countries. I'd suggest doing more research to see what your country's guidelines are:

From [this website](https://visaguide.world/us-visa/appointment/): How to Reschedule a US Visa Appointment?

> To reschedule a US nonimmigrant visa appointment, you can either call
>   the VAC or change the date and time online. You
>   must provide a valid reason as to why you are rescheduling so that the
>   US Embassy takes it into account.
>
> To reschedule a US immigrant visa appointment, you must contact the
>   NVC and explain your reasons for wanting to reschedule. You must
>   provide your case number or application number and let them know of a
>   time that is convenient for you so they can try to get you that
>   appointment.
>   If you reschedule more than once, then you
>   may be required to pay a new visa application fee as a penalty.

[This site](https://www.vfsglobal.com/en/individuals/article-got-questions.html) suggests that the maximum number of times you can reschedule is actually two. Further,

> If you need to travel urgently, miss your pre-booked appointment, or
>   simply cannot book an appointment at your preferred date and time, the
>   Walk-in Without Appointment service, available for select countries,
>   allows you to submit your visa application on a day you choose.

As per [this site](https://www.quora.com/Can-I-reschedule-my-VI-after-my-OFC-is-done):

> Yes, it is possible to reschedule your VI if your OFC has already been
>   completed. If you login to your Applicant Homepage, you will see a
>   'Reschedule Appointment' Tab which will directly show you the
>   available slots for Visa Interview, by skipping the OFC appointment
>   page, since your OFC will already be completed.

From [this site](https://www.truvisa.com/t/reschedule-us-visa-interview-vac-appointment-in-india/1075/2):

> Yes, you can reschedule if you have missed your appointment date and
>   interview.
>
> Your application will be marked as ‘NO SHOW’ after 24-48 hours of your
>   scheduled interview date, and then the rescheduling option will be
>   available to you.
>
> Please note if you are rescheduling the appointments, you may have to
>   reschedule both (OFC and Visa officer) the interview again.
>
> You can log in to your profile on www.ustraveldocs.com for
>   choosing the available date for rescheduling your interview.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Just to be safe,I went for the OFC appointment. But they already had my data from previous appointment. It worked out in the end.